# drush sqlq --file on remote server with local file

Tags: drush, ssh

Im trying to run run write a command where I can execute remote queries stored local.

I was trying:

```
drush @remote.master sqlq < src/sql/data.sql
```

but no luck, also tried the option --file=path/to/file but it's only for remote files :(

Any ideas?

Comment: "but no luck" - please explain. What you expected to happen? What really happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`cat src/sql/data.sql | drush @remote.master sql-cli`

Comment: This work, but:

1. You need to add: `'ssh-options' => '-t'` to drush alias


2. You need to add: `;` and new line at the end of you sql files

Thanks! I can't put line breacks on this box!!!!

Comment: Any idea how I could concatenate the `;\n` at the end, on the same command so I can have "clean" sql files?

Comment: forget about -t option, the message `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. ` don't interfere with the sql actually excecuting, but -t option it mess with other drush works. Just remember to add ; at the end of sql.

Comment: Not sure why your source sql file would be missing a trailing `;` if the remote side needs it, but you could always add one on via `(cat src/sql/data.sql && echo ";") | drush ...` if you needed to.

Answer (score 1):

you should try with other command:

```
drush sql-sync --source-dump=src/sql/data.sql --target-db-url=mysql://remoteusername:remotepass@remoteserver/remotedatabase
```

Comment: can't use that solution as I don't have direct access to mysql, but trough drush aliased ssh connection :(

Comment: In that case, I think the best is copy the dump via SCP and restore it.